# Error when using lmomco and MASS packages to develop a new package

Tags: r, r-package, mass

I am trying to check a package I have created in R that uses functions from the `lmomco` package. When I use the "check" option in Rstudio I get the following error:

> byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
> Error : package or namespace load failed for 'lmomco' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> there is no package called 'MASS'

I already tried reinstalling `lmomco` and `MASS`, even using things like this:

```
install.packages("MASS", type="binary")
install.packages("MASS", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies=TRUE)
```

I need help in order to check the package I am developing.